# Why is my ViewScoped bean not surviving h:commandButton?

Tags: jsf-2

Deploying on JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final.

I have a very simple test app. It was working as expected until the other day (famous last words) and is no longer doing the most basic thing, namely setting the value of the input component and using it in the action component.  I have stripped this thing down to the basics and can not figure out what is going on.

index.xhtml is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
  <title>contacts</title>
</h:head>
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel value="Message:" />
    <h:inputText value="#{contactView.siteCode}" />
    <h:commandButton  action="#{contactView.save}" value="Save" />

</h:form>

</html>
```

ViewScoped bean is here

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ContactView implements Serializable {

    public ContactView() {
    }

    private String siteCode;

    public String getSiteCode() {
        System.out.println("getSiteCode: "+ siteCode);
        return siteCode;
    }

    public void setSiteCode(String siteCode) {
        System.out.println("setSiteCode: "+ siteCode);
        this.siteCode = siteCode;
    }

    public String save(){
        System.out.println("Saving sitecode: " + siteCode);
        return "index.jsf";
    }


}
```

What am I doing wrong?  When I click on the save button I get this in the output

```
10:50:37,663 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) setSiteCode: 22
10:50:37,663 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Saving sitecode: null
10:50:37,663 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) getSiteCode: null
```

Comment: Possibly other day you had `@ManagedBean` annotation instead of `@Named` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the bean is managed by CDI `@Named`, not by JSF `@ManagedBean`. JSF scope annotations of the package `javax.faces.bean` only works on beans managed by JSF. On a CDI managed bean, you need to use CDI annotations from `javax.enterprise.context` instead. However, CDI doesn't have a concept of the view scope. Closest is `@ConversationScoped`, but this is more complex to manage. When you don't specify a scope on a CDI managed bean, it will default to the request scope.

Make sure that your bean is managed by JSF whenever you want to use `@ViewScoped`.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ContactView implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

Further, you also need to make sure that your action methods return `null` or `void` whenever you want to retain the view scope.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I thought I used @Named from the start, but that must be one of the things I tinkered with.  I based my app on this http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_jsf_2_ejband I see now he uses ManagedBean .  I have no recollection of changing it but anything is possible.  In its final form I want to use a redirect and put sitecode in the parameter list in the URL. I guess doing that obviates the need for ViewScoped....

Comment: Yesterday I realized/found/learned that seam-faces has an implementation of ViewScoped that works with Named. That is why my app worked with Named!  The problem started when I decided to "clean up" my POM. Bad idea.  I removed seam-faces wondering why I had added it in the first place.  Three days later I finally know why!  Perhaps I should add this as an answer and not a comment...