# Why is JSF 2 managed bean not available in result page?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a very simple app. One bean annotated with @Named @SessionScoped and 2 web pages.  home.xhtml and list.xhtml.  When I set searchForm.hostanme on the first page, and access it again on the 2nd page.  I can see from sysout statements that hostname is getting set, but there is a space where that value should be on the list.xhtml page.  It's disappearing between home and list.  Why?

home.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:form>
  <h:outputText value="Hi Mama" />
  <h:inputText value="#{searchForm.hostname}" />
  <h:commandButton action="list?faces-redirect=true" value="Devices" />
  <h:commandButton action="#{searchForm.reset}" value="Reset" immediate="true" type="reset" />
</h:form>
</html>
```

list.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <h:outputText value="Device is #{searchForm.hostname}" />
</html>
```

SearchForm.java

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SearchForm {  

    String hostname;

    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }

    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        System.out.println("hostname is "+ hostname);
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }

    public String reset(){
        System.out.println("RESETTING");
        System.out.println("hostname is "+ hostname);
        return "/index.xhtml";
    }
}
```

I'm thinking it might be a scoping issue, but I've tried several scopes and still searchForm.hostname is not avaible by the time I navigate to the list.xhtml page.

I've been reading and reading and reading up on JSF2, but I still can't resolve I hope is a simple problem.

I have a beans.xml file is in WEB-INF.

Comment: Your code says that the bean is `@RequestScoped`. The behavior described is correct if the bean is request scoped.

Comment: omg I just realized I asked almost this exact question previously. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861144/why-is-my-viewscoped-bean-not-surviving-hcommandbutton  I started working on jsf2 awhile back and haven't looked at it since.  I think it's a mis-match of libraries.

Comment: You should create an answer and mark it answered if it is the case!

Comment: Yes -- I'm going to come with something very clear and put in an answer.  Still playing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come from a seam 2 background so decided I was comfortable with ConversationScoped in this context.  It worked like a charm.

Some more thoughts that might help a confused person like me.

As I commented above, I grappled with a similar issue before [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861144/why-is-my-viewscoped-bean-not-surviving-hcommandbutton).  As the comments above suggest, this is a scope issue.  I realized that it is not only a scoping issue, it is an issue of confusion between CDI and JSF2 managed beans.

Both have a unique set of scopes, but there is some overlap, and in order to not be scratching your head over what should really not be a difficult problem, it is important to

1. Decide whether to use CDI beans or JSF2 managed beans
2. Thoroughly learn the scopes assocated with either type of bean
3. Know which one you are selecting when eclipse offers you 2 choices!

That last one has messed me up more times than I should admit.

Whether to use CDI or JSF2 just google "cdi vs. jsf2". I chose CDI since most things I read said to use CDI. I'm not sure it really makes a difference for my simple app.

Learn your scopes!! There are many articles about scopes, unfortunately I don't understand them as well as I should.

This is a classic for JSF2 users: [Communication in JSF2](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope) helpful as well. (notice same author - BalusC is a good resource for anything JSF2)

As for CDI just stick with the tutorial on Oracle's website.

And as for which library to import -- both JSF and CDI have a SessionScoped, and I think also RequestScoped:

- CDI scopes are in javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
- JSF scopes are in javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped

I consistently just take the first thing eclipse offers me.  It can really screw you up so pay attention!